# Passing array and other data through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

This is my javascript function....
But my php controller getting all values but not the array not sure why ? Need help.....
Thanks in advance :)

```
function submitForm(){
    var id = $('#id').val(); 
    var supplier_id = $('#supplier_id').val();
    var description = $('#description').val();
    var numofpro = $('#numofpro').val();

    var product_id = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<numofpro;i++){
        product_id[i] = $('#product_id'+(i+1)).val();               
    }
    var payment_mode = $('#payment_mode').val();
    //description = description.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');     
    $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url(); ?>edit/save_purchase", //The url where the server req would we made.
            data: "id="+id+"&supplier_id="+supplier_id+"&description="+description+"&product_id="+product_id+"&payment_mode="+payment_mode,
            dataType: "html", //Return data type (what we expect).
            beforeSend:function(){
                //alert("asds");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //alert("Edited");
                alert(data);

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Try `data: {id:id, supplier_id:supplier_id, description:description, product_id:product_id, payment_mode:payment_mode}` instead of your long string. That's how it should be set.

Comment: it solved my problem...thnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you pass a string, not an array :) try it:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?= base_url(); ?>edit/save_purchase",
        type: "POST"
        data: {id : id, supplier_id : supplier_id, description : description, product_id : product_id, payment_mode : payment_mode},
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend:function(){
           //alert("asds");
        },
        success: function(data) {
        //alert("Edited");
            alert(data);
         }
        });
```

in you php use :

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST);
//some php code
//some $result;
// if $result arr then
echo json_encode($result);
// else 
echo json_encode(array('data' => $result))
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn that array into a string in JS. Before sending it, do this:

```
JSON.stringify(product_id);
```

Once you receive it in PHP, you need to decode it.

```
$decoded = json_decode($_POST['product_id'])
```